# Is it possible to measure the total width of a lazyrow with the contents included?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Say I have a lazyRow and I was wondering if it was possible to measure the total width of this lazyrow. So including content. Also in the scenario where I don't know the total width of each list item.

The idea is that by being able to measure this, I can create a draggable composable which could move the lazyrow based on the offset.